# How to connect an old SCSI Tandberg QIC tape drive with current systems?

Tags: hard-drive, connector, scsi, tape

I currently have a ton of QIC-250MB tapes that I would like to read from (its been 30 years). I have a Tandberg TDC 3600 SCSI interfaced tape drive but I am lost how to connect it. In the past, with the computers then, they had a SCSI port where I could directly connect it. However, with computers today, SCSI interfaces appear to be obsolete. To be more specific, this is how it looks from the front:

[image]

and from the back:

[image]

The back looks like a 50 Pin Centronics. I am just not sure how I can connect such a device using modern computers, if at all. Any suggestions or guidances would be much appreciated!

Comment: This question might have a better chance of being answered on [retrocomputing.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal SCSI-I cables used that 50-pin connector, as you can see in this [old cable for sale](https://www.disctech.com/SCSI-Cable-Internal-50pin-Ribbon-5-Device-6-connector-Brand-New?partner=1011&gclid=CjwKCAiAt4rfBRBKEiwAC678KXR7M3n-Y77R6bfhUgqInnSk-Bs_BOvM05OeRjbq4QIFR2IRp4czABoCRpUQAvD_BwE).

[image: Internal SCSI-1 ribbon cable]

You'd need to add a SCSI-1 card which would have a 25-by-two pin header (circled in orange) to connect that cable to. [image: SCSI-1 controller card with 50-pin connector circled]

Comment: Thanks a lot, back in the day I remember there was a fuss about terminators. Is this something I need to worry about? So essentially I would connect this card to a computer that still has a PCI bus?

Comment: I did exactly the same thing with a qic3020 cartridge - Thankfully it used parallel, but modern ports were no good so had to buy a toshiba libretto win3.11 laptop! You may need to buy / obtain an early PC due to driver issues. The PCI version of that card may be like gold dust so make sure the old PC has the ISA slots - Far more popular for scsi back then. As far as termination goes check if your tape device has auto termination, otherwise make sure you get a terminator with the cable.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Thanks, thats real interesting to hear you bought a toshiba libretto! If I were to boot from linux, what is your gut feeling regarding driver issues? Are they inherent to the software or the hardware here?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Do you mean SCSI adapter drivers, or the Tandberg tape drivers? (I had the impression SCSI has a fairly standard 'tape access' protocol, just like it has disk access.)

Comment: The 6 by 2 pin header matrix on the back does not identify an option for termination, so, yes, you would need to plan to find a terminator and put it on the last connector in the ribbon cable.

Comment: Finding old SCSI cards can be hard. And they can be expensive, as they get rarer.

Comment: Stick to what the initial spec of the tape drive requires. The 165 page manual should give you more info. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/908016/Tandberg-Data-Tdc-3640.html?page=1#manual